# Problem to run Wine from the store

Tags: wine

I am running the latest version of Elementary, I am new to Linux, I want to run Wine but every time I install it through the official store it installs normal but it is not listed in the application menu, even though it is listed in the installed list. I always keep the system up to date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See if Wine is installed by running it from the command line, just type wine and hit tab a few times - all the options matching wine should be listed. You can also run wine --version, which should yield the version that is installed.

Also, wine doesn't add anything to the app menu because it doesn't create a . desktop file. This thread should help you: https://forums.puri.sm/t/wine-installed-not-in-list-of-applications/2563

Comment: Boa tarde Renan, vi que você é brasileiro, eu também sou.
 Vou testar hoje a noite, mas não sei, testei tanta coisa, creio que eu tenha que rodar alguns comandos de limpeza pra remover tudo antes e começar de novo, porem já cheguei a executar o comando Wine e o Wine version, mas sem sucesso. Nesse quesito o Linux é ligeiramente mais confuso para novos usuários pois no Windows instalamos sempre da mesma forma e tudo é listado como instalado. Mas é só aprender que da certo...

Comment: Você usa a tempo essa distro?